# News article cite in text \citejournal

Tags: citing, apacite

I have a news article that I want to cite in my introduction. So far I have used `\citeyear` and `\citeauthor` to just cite the particular year and author.  Is there a complement for this e.g.. `\citejournal`?

The result would be as follows e.g. "The New York Times published an article in 1981." Where `The New York Times` is the journal which should lead to the reference.

This is my reference set up:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\input{general/bibliography}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\makeatletter
\NAT@longnamesfalse
\makeatother
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\newcommand{\BBAA}{\&}% between authors in parenthetical cites and ref. list
\newcommand{\BBAB}{and}% between authors in in-text citation
\newcommand{\BAnd}{\&}% for ``Ed. \& Trans.'' in ref. list
``

@article{altman1981,
 author  = {{Lawrence K. Altman}},
 year    = {1981},
 title   = {Rare Cancer Seen in 41 Homosexuals},
 journal = {The New York Times},
 url     = {https://www.nytimes.com/1981/07/03/us/rare-cancer-seen-in-41-homosexuals.html},
 urldate = {2022-06-26}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting an example of an entry from the bib file you wish to cite by its `journal` field. Incidentally, are you using the `@newspaper` entry type for this entry?

Comment: `author  = {{Lawrence K. Altman}},` should really be `author  = {Lawrence K. Altman},`. You should not force a particular name formatting, this should be up to the style you are using. Note that if I try to turn your code into a compilable example document I get errors from `\newcommand{\BBAA}` and friends. The document compiles if I change them to `\renewcommand`s.

Comment: But now to answer your question: `apacite` does not expose the `journal` field to its cite commands in a convenient way, so there is no obvious way to define `\citejournal` or the like. A simple workaround would be to try https://www.ctan.org/pkg/usebib. A not so simple workaround would be to patch lots of internal macros of `apacite` to try and expose the `journal` field (that might even be possible without messing with the `.bst` file, but would probably still require extensive work).